# "Apt configuration problem. An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed"

Tags: apt, ubiquity, system-installation

I am trying to load v11.04 onto my HP desktop hard drive using a USB drive.  I used the same USB drive to load the system on my Dell netbook and it loaded successfully.  But trying to load on the desktop I get the error

> Apt configuration problem. An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed

The installer then crashes.  I have nothing in the CD drive.  I can boot the system from the USB drive and it works fine.  I have tried all options on the load with the same crash each time. I baffled as I successfully loaded my netbook with the same USB with no problems.

Comment: Hi Paul, can you boot the machine again and immediately when you see the little person and keyboard icons at the bottom center the screen, press the Space bar & select your language & then choose "Check disc for defects"? If it fails, is it possible to try re-making the USB drive? Also, what method did you use to create the USB?

Comment: By load, do you mean install?

Comment: bug in ubiquity https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/658865 CONFIRMED but not solved.

Comment: I had this problem today with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. It happened twice when installing from the same stick. After formatting the stick and putting Ubuntu back on it, the installation from stick to harddisk was OK.

Comment: The source from Kodi helped me out. (Greatful as I didn't need to repartition my USB) - https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=126351

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, I assume you are trying to install Natty on your HP desktop from a USB.

So, I looked up the error and reached Ubiquity [bug 768239](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/768239) where **[comment 11](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/768239/comments/1)** is might be useful.

> **Bug 768239** is
>   11.04 Installer crashed, apt configuration problem:
>   InstallStepError: >AptSetup failed with code 127

Notes in that comment suggest [bug 658865](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/658865) is the cause for this...

> When trying to install Ubuntu 10.10 from USB, ubiquity crashes with this message: "An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed."
>
> **Root of problem**
>   The problem is that the file structure on the usb differs to what is on a livecd and apt-setup is unaware of this.

That bug goes on to discuss two alternatives.

1. Remove the script that causes the error, when installing from a Live setup ("Try Ubuntu"):

   > sudo rm /usr/lib/ubiquity/apt-setup/generators/40cdrom
2. Create the files as they are expected
     To resolve this, simply copy the contents of filesystem.squashfs on the iso into the usb stick.

You'll get more context in the two bug records.

Comment: Removing the script worked for me in Ubuntu 13.10. Thanks!