# Xubuntu 14.04 install fails on Dell Inspiron B130 with Broadcom 4318

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, dell, broadcom, 32-bit

I have a Dell Inspiron B130 I am trying to install 32-bit Xubuntu 14.04 on. The install of 13.10 was AOK but the update failed catastrophically, so I am reinstalling from scratch.

WiFi and the Ethernet port work AOK in Windows 8.1u1 (70 secs to boot) and Mint 16 Cinnamon (135 secs to boot), but neither work in 14.04 and the install fails on the Dell; it won't find the network (which also fails on Bodhi 32-bit).

Since any install fails whether or not I have an Internet connection (with "An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed") whether or not I select to update apps in the install, whether or not I choose to install MP3 and other Multiverse items, I am unable to install then go get drivers.

Comment: For wifi see [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers). Ethernet should just work, what error do you get?

Comment: I created three different Live USB devices; one with Unetbootin from Xubuntu 14.04 on another machine, one with the Univeral ISB Installer from Windows, the last with MultiSysteme pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux . #1 and #3 fail in the same way, before I can get to the point of replacing drivers. #2 stalls for at least 15 minutes so far after selecting 'Download updates while installing' and 'Install this third-party software'.

Comment: Try the solution in ["Apt configuration problem. An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78403/apt-configuration-problem-an-attempt-to-configure-apt-to-install-additional-pa)

Comment: Have you tried using apt-offline? Download the signature (from different system) more of a work-around than full solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need internet connection to install Xubuntu or any Linux distro?
I always install Linux OSes without internet and then I a run total system update. These two methods are same actually.

Comment: Because, 14.04 demands it. I get "An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed" when I try to install, with or without net.

Comment: A strange problem! I never faced this thing. Well the problem is your installation medium I believe. I recommend you to use another DVD and try to burn ISO file at moderate speed this time. (Use this software if you're on Windows http://www.burnaware.com). (OR) Try to install it using USB stick if your PC supports USB boot. Tutorials can be found everywhere on the internet.

Comment: MANI, please see comments to original post, above.

Comment: Okay. Why don't you try a DVD once instead of pen drive ? It's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have had the same problem but you can make a icloud server from http://www.icloud.com, and use a usb stick whit ubootin using live cd if the clude server dos not work whit the installing of xubuntu, and install it directly from windows 8.1, and you can also use boot settings it will also install the software, and the make internet connection work at the terminal enter:

```
  rfkill list
  lspci
```

give the output if network if it is block or not, and there you can then enter if down network is down:

```
  rfkill unblock soft
  rfkill unblock hard
```

then enter in the terminal:

```
  lsmod wlan0
```

then use nmap enter in the terminal:

```
  nmap -v -iR 10000 -Pn -p port (normal 80)
```

and this maybe might work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Mint 17 64-bit still has this problem from ISOs put on USB drives via unetbootin. But the problem does not exist when the ISO was put on the USB drive via usb-creator-gtk.