# "An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed"

Tags: usb, kylin, yumi

I am trying to install Ubuntu Kylin, but everytime I am about to finish the installation it shows the following message: ''An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from CD failed.''

I tried doing a bunch of things online already such as in the other post: 
["Apt configuration problem. An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78403/apt-configuration-problem-an-attempt-to-configure-apt-to-install-additional-pa)

but still doesn't work. What should I do? The computer I am trying to install it on is completely empty, it has a SSD, i3.

I already tried using the following softwares to make a bootable usb: YUMI, live usb install, rufus and universal usb installer.

I also tried using three different usb sticks. None of them worked.

-Please help me making a bootable usb that works well.

Comment: Have you tried LinuxLive USB Creator?