# For external hard drive. APT configuration problem.An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed

Tags: apt, system-installation, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have this problem I cannot solve. It appears during the installation process of Ubuntu 18.04 on my External Hard Drive. When the process starts checking the APT it gives me the aforementioned error. 
I have seen the solution on the forum to write this command in the terminal:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/ubiquity/apt-setup/generators/40cdrom
```

But it does not work for me. It only says that no such file exists.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? If you need more details that I have not mentioned here, please ask me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776721/problem-with-sudo-apt-get-update-the-repository-cdrom-does-not-have-a-releas)

Comment: Welcome to askUbuntu. Please copy the error message which you get and add it to the answer as code snippet

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Apt configuration problem. An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78403/apt-configuration-problem-an-attempt-to-configure-apt-to-install-additional-pa)